# How to call SecItemCopyMatching in Xcode 7 beta 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode7-beta4

In previous versions of Xcode 6 and 7 with Swift, this syntax would work:

```
    var secureItemValue: Unmanaged<AnyObject>?

    let statusCode: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainItemQuery, &secureItemValue)
    if statusCode == errSecSuccess
    {
        let opaquePointer = secureItemValue?.toOpaque()

        let secureItemValueData = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(opaquePointer!).takeUnretainedValue()

        // Use secureItemValueData...
    }
```

However, the SecItemCopyMatching declaration has changed in Xcode 7 beta 4:

OLD:  `func SecItemCopyMatching(_ query: CFDictionary, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) -> OSStatus`

NEW:   `func SecItemCopyMatching(_ query: CFDictionary!, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<AnyObject>?>) -> OSStatus`

...and now the secureItemValue type does not match.

The mechanism was confusing before to extract the result, and I'm hoping it is  somehow easier with the new declaration, but I don't know how to declare the correct type for the secureItemValue variable and extract the result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works on Xcode 7 beta 4

```
var dataTypeRef: AnyObject?

    let status: OSStatus = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&dataTypeRef) { SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, UnsafeMutablePointer($0)) }

    if status == noErr {
        return dataTypeRef as? NSData
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Nice, @Maximilian. Would not have figured this out in a million years!

Comment: If an object is optional, its default to nil, so `var dataTypeRef: AnyObject?` and `var dataTypeRef: AnyObject? = nil` are the exact same

Comment: Yes Maximilian you are right, I am going to delete my comment.

Comment: I think the first statement can be simplified to `let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378013#32378367) you can just remove `Unmanaged<>` around AnyObject:

```
var secureItemValue: AnyObject?

let statusCode: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainItemQuery, &secureItemValue)
```