# iOS 9 : SecItemCopyMatching returns successful status code but key is nil

Tags: xcode, rsa, keychain, ios9

I am trying to import private key into keychain using`SecItemAdd` method returns `OSStatus` 0 but when I try to retrieve that key from key chain using `SecItemCopyMatch`, It returns nil data but `OSStatus` is 0 means success

Please refer from Apple developer forum [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13748)

Comment: getting the same result, do you have any successful solution for now?

Comment: No..waiting for iOS9 public release.

Comment: if you need it ASAP you can try to make swift injection in your code using this solution for swift -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549059/how-to-call-secitemcopymatching-in-xcode-7-beta-4

Comment: Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

The bug occurs due to malformed public key refer https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15129

If you use Basic Encoding Rules library here's the solution.

To fix your public key you need to insert nil byte before modulus data.
https://github.com/StCredZero/SCZ-BasicEncodingRules-iOS/issues/6#issuecomment-136601437

P.S. For me fix was as simple as:

```
const char fixByte = 0;
NSMutableData * fixedModule = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&fixByte length:1];
[fixedModule appendData:modulusData];
```

Comment: No My problem is importing private key not public key... I haven't tried to import public key

Comment: You just save my life,thank you very much,how can this simple solution do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! you're my hero!

In my case.

- Before

  ```
  NSData *modBits = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:mod options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  ```
- After

  ```
  const char fixByte = 0;
  NSMutableData * modBits = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&fixByte length:1];

  NSData *tmpmodBits = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:mod options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

  [modBits appendData:tmpmodBits];
  ```