# Generate keychain key with swift 2.0

Tags: swift

A function that creates a key pair (private, public)

```
public func generateKeyPair(publicKeyTag: String, privateKeyTag:String, keySize: Int) -> KeyPair? {

    let privateKeyAttr: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: privateKeyTag
    ];

    let publicKeyAttr: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: publicKeyTag
    ];

    let keyPairAttr: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as! String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as! String: keySize,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as! String: privateKeyAttr,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as! String: publicKeyAttr
    ];

    var publicKeyPtr, privateKeyPtr: Unmanaged<SecKey>?;

    let error = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr, &publicKeyPtr, &privateKeyPtr)

    if( result != errSecSuccess ){
        return nil
    }

    let publicKey = publicKeyPtr!.takeRetainedValue()
    let privateKey = privateKeyPtr!.takeRetainedValue()
    return KeyPair(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privateKey)
}
```

raises

```
Cannot convert value of type 'inout Unmanged<SecKey>?' ... expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<SecKey?> ...'
```

this sounds `sound` when I look up [the api for SecKeyGeneratePair](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyGeneratePair) so lets change the type of `publicKeyPtr, privateKeyPtr`:

```
public func generateKeyPair(publicKeyTag: String, privateKeyTag:String, keySize: Int) -> KeyPair ? {

    let privateKeyAttr: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: privateKeyTag
    ]

    let publicKeyAttr: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: publicKeyTag
    ]

    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: keySize,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: privateKeyAttr,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String: publicKeyAttr
    ]

    var publicKeyPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecKey?> = nil
    var privateKeyPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecKey?> = nil

    let result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, publicKeyPtr, privateKeyPtr)

    if( result != errSecSuccess ){
        return nil
    }

    let publicKey = Unmanaged<SecKey>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(publicKeyPtr)).takeRetainedValue()
    let privateKey = Unmanaged<SecKey>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(privateKeyPtr)).takeRetainedValue()

    publicKeyPtr.destroy()
    privateKeyPtr.destroy()

    return KeyPair(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privateKey)
}
```

but when I use the function then publicKey and privateKey raises:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, ...
```

and when I insert a breakpoint I realize that the pointers (`publicKeyPtr, privateKeyPtr) are never set.

so how do I migrate the swift 1.2 code to swift 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public func generateKeyPair(publicKeyTag: String, privateKeyTag:String, keySize: Int) -> KeyPair?  {

    let privateKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: privateKeyTag
    ]
    let publicKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: publicKeyTag
    ]
    let parameters: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: keySize,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateKeyAttr,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicKeyAttr
    ]

    var publicKey: SecKey?
    var privateKey: SecKey?
    let result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey)

    if result != errSecSuccess {
        return nil
    }
    return KeyPair(publicKey: publicKey!, privateKey: privateKey!)
}
```

You can pass in-out `&` expressions to `UnsafeMutablePointer` parameters.

See also: [swift 2.0 keychain type errors for SecItemCopyMatching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32378013/3804019)

Comment: Shouldn't `kSecAttrApplicationTag` be `NSData`? This code compiles but crashes.