# GenerateKeyPair changed in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, security

Using swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3 running under El Capitan.

Just tried this...

```
public func generateKeyPair(publicKeyTag: String, privateKeyTag:String,` `keySize: Int) -> KeyPair?  {

    let privateKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: privateKeyTag
]
let publicKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
    kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: publicKeyTag
]
let parameters: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: keySize,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateKeyAttr,
    kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicKeyAttr
]

var publicKey: SecKey?
var privateKey: SecKey?
let result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey)

if result != errSecSuccess {
    return nil
}
return KeyPair(publicKey: publicKey!, privateKey: privateKey!)
```

And unfortunately it produces nil, nil as a public/private key pair.

I called it with:

```
generateKeyPair("ch.blah.public",privateKeyTag: "ch.blah.private",keySize: 32)
```

What am I missing here? Apparently this used to work?

[Generate keychain key with swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951051/generate-keychain-key-with-swift-2-0)

The error no it prints is 0; which sort of suggests it did work?

Comment: Xcode 7.3 is shipped with Swift 2.2. Are you sure you use Swift 3.0?

Comment: I guess, cause it keeps suggesting changes I need to make to fit swift 3.0. But no I am not 100% certain. Its Xcode 7.3 7D175.

Comment: The compiler suggests you to prepare to move to Swift 3.0 'cause it will introduce source-breaking changes. You are now using Swift 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an invalid key length for RSA. Also, `kSecAttrApplicationTag` needs to be a `NSData` object, not a `NSString` object.

```
public func generateKeyPair(publicKeyTag: String, privateKeyTag:String, keySize: Int) {       
    let privateKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: privateKeyTag.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    ]
    let publicKeyAttr: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: publicKeyTag.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    ]
    let parameters: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: keySize,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateKeyAttr,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicKeyAttr
    ]

    var publicKey: SecKey?
    var privateKey: SecKey?
    let result = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey)

    if result != errSecSuccess {
        print("Result: \(result)")
        return
    }

    print("Public: \(publicKey)")
    print("Private: \(privateKey)")
}

generateKeyPair("ch.blah.public", privateKeyTag: "ch.blah.private", keySize: 2048)
```

Comment: Sulthan, you are worth your weight in GOLD! Work perfectly now :)