# Cannot convert value of type 'Unmanaged<AnyObject>?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?' working with Keychain, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, keychain

Trying to insert some data in the Keychain. I have the following code:

```
func create(attributes: [String: AnyObject]) {
    var rawResult: Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
    let rawStatus = SecItemAdd(attributes, &rawResult)

    let result: AnyObject? = rawResult?.takeRetainedValue()
}
```

This won't work... shows the error from the question title. Found a possible "solution" on a similar problem an user experienced on StackOverflow. They told him to remove **Unmanaged<AnyObject>?** and replace it with **AnyObject?**. The problem is that I need *takeRetainedValue()* method which is present in the *Unmanaged* class.

Comment: *"Found a possible "solution" on a similar problem"* – What about providing the link here? Most probably you can remove the `takeRetainedValue()` as well.

Comment: Here it is.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378013/swift-2-0-keychain-type-errors-for-secitemcopymatching?rq=1)